# Passing doGet the parameter

Tags: google-apps-script

I would like to run lock and unlock with owner privileges.
The lock function works, but the unlock function does not.
Am I sending the id parameter correctly?
Can someone tell you what is wrong?
Is IF OK?
Is script block and unlock also ok?

```
function doGet(e){
  var id = e.parameter.id;
  //block
  if(id == 1){
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    spreadsheet.getRange('D10').activate();
    var protection = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().protect();
    protection.addEditors(['user1@email.com']);
    spreadsheet.getRange('A1').activate();
    protection.removeEditors(['user2@email.com', 'user3@email.com']);
    } else if (id == 2) {
      //unlock
      var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
      spreadsheet.getRange('E19').activate();
      var allProtections = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET);
      var protection = allProtections[0];
      protection.remove();
      } 
  return ContentService.createTextOutput();
  };

function block() {
  UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://script.google.com/macros/s/###################################################/exec?id=1', {headers: {authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}});
}

function unlock() {
    UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://script.google.com/macros/s/###################################################/exec?id=2', {headers: {authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}});
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should add method and possibly muteHttpExceptions

Comment: `The lock function works, but the unlock function does not.` What does this mean? Are you getting any error? Is the code just not entering the `else if` block? Did you deploy a new version after adding the `else if` block?

Comment: When I run the block function like this:
`var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('E19').activate();
  var allProtections = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET);
  var protection = allProtections[0];
  protection.remove();'
it works. So the blocked sheet is unlocked.
I run both as owner and user.
When I run it as described above, it doesn't.
I implement scrypt from scratch with every change.
Script name doesn't matter?
If I change to:
if (id == 1) {...}
if (id == 2) {....}
it also doesn't work.

Comment: Could you please clarify about `Did you deploy a new version after adding the else if block?`. Considering that it is entering the first code block, it looks like the passing of the parameter is working, I thought you just didn't update the deployment after adding the `else if` block, so you're executing an outdated version that doesn't contain this block.